div overflowing outside body element while viewport width reduces
Following is my code


body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}


div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    width: 950px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 3em;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    div {
        width: auto;
    }

}
<div></div>



I want to see how media query is working. So, if I reduce the viewport width, at one point, horizontal scroll bar appears and further reducing the viewport width, that bar disappears. So, when the horizontal scroll bar appears, we can see that div overflowing the body border. I have set margin: 0 on the body element. So, what is happening ?

After inspecting the page and checking dev tools, I figured out that problem was with the box model. After I put a universal border-box and increasing max-width in media query slightly above the given width of the div, I could get rid of the horizontal scroll bar as I reduce the viewport width.


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  } 


body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    
}


div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    width: 950px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    padding: 3em 0 3em 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 952px) {
    div {
        width: auto;
    }

}
<div></div>



Hope this is helpful.
